# Visual Studio not stepping into same-project constructor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to debug some code, as a class is throwing an exception when called.
The code is:

```
    public TrackingStrategy1(string Name, RobotGeometry geometry)
    {
        trackSystem = new TrackSystem(geometry, Name);
    }
```

which calls (In the same project):

```
    public TrackSystem(RobotGeometry geometry, string Name)
    {
        finder = new FindModel(geometry);  //breakpoint inserted here fails
        finder.InitModel();

        finder.useGPU = false;
    }
```

I am getting the exception 'Method Not Found: TrackSystem.FindModel..ctor(RobotGeometry). However, a break point inserted at this point is not hit. If I comment out the new line, I get the same exception for  the next line.

FindModel is referenced in another project contained in the solution, which I have re-referenced to several times, followed by a rebuild.

Why does Visual Studio not stop at breakpoints inserted in this constructor?

Comment: What language is this? C#? This is definitely not C++.

Comment: @AndreyT: Pre-emptively tagged as C#. It could just as well be Java, but the tagging of `Visual Studio 2010` suggests that it's C# based on the function signature syntax.

Comment: Did I tag it C++? I must have been half asleep. C# is correct.

Comment: If you are getting the error "Method Not Found" then your *real* problem is a broken build.  `FindModel` is in a separate project?  You should probably confirm that the assemblies in your `bin` folder are all up to date and correct.

Answer (score 0):

Before loading each class, Visual Studio was checking for the existence of all external dll method calls.
Because this occurs before the constructor is called, the break points in the constructor are never called.

In this case, the reason for failure was that 2 different projects were referencing different versions of FindModel - and the wrong one for this project was used in the build.